# Construct POJO with same properties but different object names

Tags: java, pojo

I am wanting to construct an array of objects, that have the same properties of type String:

1. property1
2. property2

With this POJO, I intend to serialize into JSON with Jackson.

I would like the serialized array of objects to be in this format (each object having a different name):

```
 "array":[  
         {  
            "LORUM_IPSUM":{  
               "property1":"",
               "property2":""
            }
         },
         {  
            "DOLAR_SIT":{  
               "property1":"",
               "property2":""
            }
         }
]
```

Is there a Jackson annotation where I can use the same Class, but name each object differently? I've shortened this example for brevity, but there'll be over 20 objects.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It is maybe easier to use a list of maps for the outer structure.

Comment: You can use `@JsonProperty("myname")` for that.

Comment: Where do names "LORUM_IPSUM" and "DOLAR_SIT" come from? Annotations? Another property?

Comment: @AhmadShahwan - the names will come from a Builder method where I want to add all of the objects.

Comment: @jAC, thank you for your reply. Will that mean I need to explicitly declare each object with its respective class?

Comment: @Ben Yes, so this can only be used if you have some solution that is not dynamic. E.g. a fixed set of Services returning an `ServiceStatus` but I'm not sure, if this is exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, the solution won't be dynamic, I could, essentially, derive them from a static list as the names of each objects will be constant.